# Fixed position div inside reponsive div with angularjs and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page layout that involves a fixed sidebar to the left and a main container on the rest of the page to the right. Inside that right side container which is a div I have 2 elements

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    <custom directive>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-9">
    <another custom directive>
</div>
```

The content of the second div is long so scrolling is implied.
What I want to do is make the first div sticky. So I applied a `position:fixed` to it in css but that takes it out of the context of the right side container which means the css classes responsive width don't work anymore. Also the 2 divs overlap.

I am looking for a clean way to handle this. The best I thought of is using a dummy div like so :

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3 dummy-div">

</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3 sticky-div">
    <custom directive>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-9">
    <another custom directive>
</div>
```

With this I thought of creating an element directive that uses jquery to set the witdh of sticky-div to the width of the dummy-div.
I still think this isn't a very nice solution though, and was wondering if there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

First off do not duplicate Class you should just have one `class=""` with all of your class' inside it.

Instead of creating a dummy div to compensate from flow removal you should just give the non fixed `<div>` a `margin` or `padding` to compensate for the loss of the `fixed` `<div>`.

You could just use j query to gram the `width` of the container and inject like you mentioned.

another idea would be to use dynamic widths and match them up to the container.

e.g. `50%` couple that with `calc` and I don't see any reason why you cant achieve the exact width of the so called parent of the fixed `<div>`.

Comment: You are right of course about the duplicate class I have edited my code. I ended up using media queries and using a dynamic width as you said. The important thing for me was that depending on screen size that fixed position div would have to take part a different percentage of the screen

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went for in the end was keeping the dummy div and then calculating the width of the fixed div with media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
    position: fixed;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 1.3em;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    position: relative;
    width: 95% ;
    margin-right: 1.3em;
  }
```

I also needed the div to not be fixed for small screens where the layout goes vertical.